# How to find out if the angle between two vectors is external or internal?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, trigonometry, angle

I know how to find out angle between 2 vectors, but it always gives me internal angle, but I want it to give me always the angle in anticlockwise direction, even if it is greater then 180.
I'm using C++ but it is not really important because I need to get the theory.

This is what I am using now [image: formula]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the `atan2(y,x)` function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). If you give it the two components of a 2D vector, it will give you the angle of the vector from the x axis, in the counter-clockwise direction. To solve your specific problem try:

```
atan2(v_y, v_x) - atan2(u_y, u_x)
```

Then you can add or subtract 360 degrees if the answer is out of the range of angles you desire.

Comment: Just be aware that atan2() generally gives a result in the range (-pi,pi], so if it's negative, you need to add 2pi to it first. (In the case where one angle is greater than 0 and the other less than 0.)