# How to find out if the angle between two vectors is external or internal? (in 3D space)

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, trigonometry, angle

I read this post,

---

[How to find out if the angle between two vectors is external or internal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054593/how-to-find-out-if-the-angle-between-two-vectors-is-external-or-internal)

I know how to find out angle between 2 vectors, but it always gives me internal angle, but I want it to give me always the angle in anticlockwise direction, even if it is greater then 180.

---

I got similar question.

The only different is my two vectors are in 3D space,

A = (x1, y1, z1)

B = (x2, y2, z2)

How to find out the angle between two vectors is external or internal?

(From A to B, anticlockwise direction, 0~360)

Comment: For two arbitrary vectors in 3d, isn't it always the case that the angle between them will be less than 180, from certain perspectives; just specifying "anticlockwise" isn't enough to change that, I believe.

Comment: I.e. the two vectors (if they're not parallel) will form a plane. If you look at the plane from one side and measure the angle anticlockwise between them, you'll get one answer. But if you look at the plane from the opposite side and measure anticlockwise, you'll get a different answer. One of those two answers will always be less than 180.

Comment: hmm.. I should add "Always from vector A to vector B, anticlockwise direction". (The plane is parallel to triangle "zero point"-"A"-"B")

Comment: Have you read my second comment and thought about it?

Comment: I see. so there's no answer for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clockwise or counter-clockwise in 3D space. If you have given two vectors A and B, there is exactly one angle between them. It's a pretty canonical choice: The smaller of the two angles connecting them in the plane which is defined by A and B (i.e. the plane which is parallel to both of these vectors. There is only one choice unless A and B are parallel).

So if you want the larger of those angles, just subtract the smaller angle (which is usually called *the angle between A and B*) from 360.